# opencv save filtered Image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm trying to save a filtered/hybrid image after manipulating it with OpenCV in Jupyter Notebook on a mac.  Everything goes fine until I try to save the image.  I have tried saving it as .jpg, .bmp. and .png.  I've tried each of those and multiplying the image by 255 as well as not multiplying.  The resulting saved file is either completely black or completely white depending on whether I multiplied by 255.

```
im1 = cv2.imread(im1_file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
im1 = cv2.cvtColor(im1, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY) / 255.0

# filtering and cropping operations

cv2.imwrite('hybrid_image.jpg', cropped_image*255)
```

I also tried 'converting' it back into a bgr image.  But it gives an error of `'depth' is 6 (CV_64F)`

```
cropped_image_255 = cropped_image*255.0
convertedimage = cv2.cvtColor(cropped_image_255, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
cv2.imwrite('hybrid_image.bmp', convertedimage)
```

Comment: Why are you reading a grayscale image and again trying to convert it to gray again in first two lines?

Comment: When you divide by 255.0, you will get a floating point result. BMP files cannot store floats.

Comment: The fix is replacing cv2.imwrite line with
```
cropped_image = cropped_image * 255 # Still floats
cv2.imwrite('hybrid_image.jpg', cropped_image.astype(np.uint8))
```

Comment: @SriRaghuMalireddi Awesome!  For some reason, I had to change the first line to `* 256` otherwise it put weird white artifacts on the top of the image.  But worked!  Can you make that an answer so I can mark it as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for your problem is converting the Image type to unsigned 8-bit integer before saving.

You can replace the following line:

```
cv2.imwrite('hybrid_image.jpg', cropped_image*255)
```

with

```
cropped_image = cropped_image * 255  # Still (can be) floats
cv2.imwrite('hybrid_image.jpg', cropped_image.astype(np.uint8))
```

Please make sure that before converting to `np.uint8` your image doesn't have any numbers above 255. Or else, OpenCV will clamp them to white pixel (255 value).

Comment: That's a good reminder.  `numpy.clip()` does a good job of clipping off <0 and >255